# Register DHCP hostname in DNS only if a domain member

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dhcp

I have an Active Directory domain, where the Domain Controller also runs our DHCP service and was recently updated to Windows Server 2019. This DHCP service is also used for a public wifi network on a different vlan (separate scope). However, some of our domain-joined laptops will also tend to use this public network.

One of the options for the DHCP server is to automatically update the DNS service to register the hostname/IP at the time the IP is issued. I want to use this option on the public wifi scope, but I want to limit it to only our domain-joined computers.

Is this possible?

Comment: I dont think there is a way, but does using DHCP name protection could mitigate the risk of DDNS in your public zone ? else I would think to add a guess wifi zone (and a secure one) to the same location, as it could allow at the same time more restriction for guess computers to not access your ressource.

Comment: We have a guest zone... but the staff equipment tends to end up there quite often anyway. We also have a few special public stations for conference rooms where want mDNS discovery to work from public devices for AirPlay. Right now we've placed these wired devices on the guest wifi vlan. Otherwise I'd just turn off the feature on the scope. I'll probably end up needing to set up some kind of bonjour gateway, but I'd really like to avoid that can of worms.